# command w and who shows 0 users are logged in

Tags: command-line, who

Currently I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Problem which I am having now is that who and w commands who 0 users are logged in system.

```
mypc:~$ who
mypc:~$ w
 22:14:10 up 12 min,  0 users,  load average: 0.52, 0.58, 0.59
 USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
```

[image]

I am logged in the system, but why are these commands showing that 0 users are logged in currently?

Comment: Is this a regular Ubuntu system - or Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: @steeldriver WSL

Comment: @steeldriver looks like a dupe, is it not?

Comment: Ah, I see. I have no clue, @steeldriver, I haven't touched WSL. I voted to close, not realizing that it was tagged with `command-line`, meaning I could single-handedly close it. Game lover, if the dupe does not answer your question, please let me know and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @terdon I tried both alternatives from the link. The second one did not work absolutely so I tried the first one. First one ... works but I have to repeat same process everytime I log in to system..

Comment: @gamelover yes, the main answer seems to be that `who` doesn't really work on WSL.

Comment: @terdon is there any other alternative which I can use to see loged in users in WSL?

Comment: No idea, sorry. Maybe you could ask a new question focusing on that instead? But I suspect you might get better answers on [su] since folks here tend to know the Linux side of things and WSL is a strange hybrid. You could use `ps aux | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u` to see the list of users currently running processes, but that would include system users as well. You can exclude those with something like `ps aux | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | grep -f <(grep -Ev 'nologin|/false' /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1)` which you could make into a function or alias.

Comment: @terdon thanks for help, but I guess downloading a VirtualBox and run ubuntu there may be will be the easiest and best solution haha :( want to cry

Comment: Do try asking a new question. Explain what you actually need (it seems unlikely that you would often have multiple users logged into a WSL system) and what you are trying to achieve (_why_ do you want the output of `who`? What are you going to do with it) and someone might be able to come up with an answer.